# "Hundreds of millions of dollars" VS "Hundreds of millions dollars"

Tags: meaning, grammatical-number

Are both "Hundreds of millions of dollars" VS "Hundreds of millions dollars" grammatically and semantically correct/identical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Millions of dollars" is the correct form.

In English, a plural noun used for counting or measuring purposes is always used with **of**, even if that noun just looks like a number:

- millions *of* dollars
- dozens *of* buckets
- thousands *of* lawyers

Note that this is a little different from simply using the number, like "two million dollars".

Comment: Thanks, there are 265000 occurrences of "millions of dollars". Should we simply consider them as "bad English"?

Comment: @PHPst - I'm not sure I understand your question.  "Millions *of* dollars" is correct, because it's a plural noun used for counting.